# JS: Get inner function arguments in asynchronous functions and execute callback

Tags: javascript

I try to write the function that returns all results of asynchronous functions and execute a callback that push into an array and log the result of every async function.

As a waiter that brings all dishes when they are all done.
I don't understand how to get the child arguments that should be returned as a result. The code of task and my not working solution is below:

The task:

```
var dishOne = function(child) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        child('soup');
    }, 1000);
};

var dishTwo = function(child) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        child('dessert');
    }, 1500);
};
waiter([dishOne, dishTwo], function(results) {
    console.log(results); // console output = ['soup', 'dessert']
});
```

My not working solution:

```
function child(arg) {
    this.arr.push(arg)
}

function waiter(funcArray, doneAll) {
    var result = {
        arr: []
    };
    let i = 0;
    const x = child.bind(result)
    funcArray.forEach(function(f) {
      f(x)
      i++;
      if(i == 2) {
        doneAll(result.arr)
      }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem is this part:

```
funcArray.forEach(function(f) {
  f(x)
  i++;
  if(i == 2) {
    doneAll(result.arr)
  }
});
```

which is a synchronous function so when you check `if(i == 2)`, you basically check, that you have called all async functions, but they did not returned anything yet, so all you know is, that the functions have been called, but `result.arr` is not yet populated.

You must move the `doneAll(result.arr)` expression into `child` callback, then it will be called by async function as it returns result.

Simpliest solution I can think of is writing your `child` as

```
function child(arg) {
    if (this.arr.push(arg) === this.allCount) this.doneAll(this.arr);
}
```

and in your `waiter` function enhance result object

```
var result = {
    arr: []
    , allCount: funcArray.length
    , doneAll: doneAll
};
```

This shall work, but has one drawback -- position of results does not keep position of functions in `funcArray`, the position of results is sorted by duration of async function, simply the first resolved would take first result etc. If this is a problem, you must pass also index to your `child` function to store result at precious position in result array and then the check by `arr.length` would not work, because JS array returns length as the highest index + 1, so if your last `funcArray` would fulfill first, it'll fill last index and the length of `result.arr` will be equal to `this.allCount`, so for keeping order of result the same as `funcArray`, you will need to store number of returned results as another number, increase that number with every new result and compare that number to `allCount`.

Or decrease allCount like so

```
function child(idx, arg) {
    this.arr[idx] = arg;
    if (--this.allCount === 0) this.doneAll(this.arr);
}
```

And modify your `waiter` function

```
function waiter(funcArray, doneAll) {
    const result = {
        arr: []
        , allCount: funcArray.length
        , doneAll: doneAll
    };

    funcArray.forEach(function(f, i) {
        f(child.bind(result, i));
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)?

```
function dishOne() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function() { resolve('soup') }, 1000)
    })
}

function dishTwo() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function() { resolve('dessert') }, 1500)
    })
}
```

Your `waiter` function:

```
function waiter(dishes, callback) {
    return Promise.all(dishes).then(callback)
}
```

And you can use it like this

```
waiter([dishOne(), dishTwo()], function(results) {
    // Invoked when all dishes are done
    console.log(results) // ['soup', dessert']
})
```

Much easier to understand. Right?

Comment: oops, sorry, I just missunderstand the question